# Is it correct to say... I can't get anywhere finishing my assignments?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I have heard people say:

> "I **can't get anywhere** finishing my assignments"

But I have also heard others say:

> "I **got nowhere** finishing my assignments"

- Are they the same meaning?
- Are they correct?

Comment: I'd feel a bit more comfortable with "I can't get anywhere near finishing my assignments".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I can't get anywhere finishing my assignments"

This doesn't really make sense because if you are "finishing" something then logically you must have *started* it, and if you've started then you have at least got *somewhere* with it!

If you mean you are struggling to start, you might say:

> I can't get anywhere with my assignments.

If you mean you are struggling to finish, you might say:

> I can't get anywhere close to finishing my assignments.

Although this may be okay in colloquial speech, technically the use of the word "can't" would mean that you do not believe it is possible to finish. If you just want to state the *current* status of your assignment, the most correct statement would be:

> I am not anywhere close to finishing my assignments.

Comment: The original question hasn't provided nearly enough detail to know what exactly OP is trying to say.  Your answer, while fine, is just a guess.  This is why we ask for more detail, and close questions that are not complete.